# DDR3 204-pin laptop RAM chip in a DDR3 240-pin desktop slot?

Tags: laptop, memory, desktop-computer, ddr3

I assume it can't be done, but I'm not a hardware guy. So, can you use a 204-pin DDR3 ram chip meant for a laptop in a desktop motherboard that has 240-pin DDR3 slots?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't. It won't fit in.

However, you could use a 204-pin-to-240-pin adapter, which looks like this:

[image: DIMM adapter]

As a final note, make sure that the laptop RAM stick's clock speed is consistent with the rest of your sticks.